# EF Code first parent child mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

This may be a duplicate qn, but i couldnt get a proper answer to this scenario. I have the following table structure:

```
public class File
{
     public int FileId { get; set; } //PK
     public int VersionID { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<FileLocal> FileLLocalCollection { get; set; }
}

public class FileLocal
{
     public int FileId { get; set; } //PK, FK
     public int LangID { get; set; } //PK,FK
     public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

I have not included the third table here(Its basically LangID (PK) & LangCode ) 
How do i specify this mapping in fluent Api so that i can load "FileLLocalCollection" with every File objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of your mapping can be done this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
    .HasMany(f => f.FileLocalCollection)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(fl => fl.FileId);

modelBuilder.Entity<FileLocal>()
    .HasKey(fl => new {fl.FileId, fl.LangId});
```

And the second part depends on the way how your `Lang` is defined. For example if you add navigation property from `FileLocal` to `Lang` you can map it this way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FileLocal>()
    .HasRequired(fl => fl.Lang)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(fl => fl.LangId);
```

Comment: and what if the relationship is one to one ie instead of "public virtual ICollection<FileLocal> FileLLocalCollection " if the property is "public virtual FileLocal FileLLocal"

Comment: In such case your FileLocal must have only FileId as PK or your File must also have LangId in its PK.

Comment: i have a scenario like this now basically. There's no LangID.. ,public class File
{
     public int FileId { get; set; } //PK
     public int VersionID { get; set; }

     public virtual FileDetail FileDetails { get; set; }
}

public class FileDetail 
{
     public int FileId { get; set; } //PK, FK
     public string FileName { get; set; }
},. Its basically one to one mapping with FileId being the PK and FK for second table like a detail table. Now how do i load FileDetail with every File object

Comment: my classes for clarity `public class File { public int FileId { get; set; } //PK public int VersionID { get; set; } public virtual FileDetail FileDetails { get; set; } } public class FileDetail { public int FileId { get; set; } //PK, FK public string FileName { get; set; } }`

Comment: Thanks Ladislav. I figured that out, basically HasRequired(e => e.FileDetails).WithRequiredPrincipal(); worked for me